# Why Rich:toolTip not work Under rich:calendar

Tags: java, php, c++

Why is Rich:toolTip not working under rich:calendar?

```
<td> 
<rich:calendar id="valuereq" requiredMessage="Requested Date Required" inputClass="inside_text" value="#{projectDetailManageBean.projectDetail.requestDate}"    datePattern="M/dd/yy" required="true">
<rich:toolTip for="valuereq">Select Request    Date</rich:toolTip>
</rich:calendar> 
</td>
```

This code should display a tooltip on the calendar box, but it didn't show .. why so?

Comment: Can explain a bit further? The question is not very clear to me.

Comment: Ahh, hidden html code ;) this needs to be formatted as code, otherwise is pretty invisible.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like jboss RichFaces. And there is [one open issue](https://jira.jboss.org/browse/RF-4986) with `rich:toolTip` inside a `rich:calendar`. Check your code if it qualifies for this bug.

Comment: we have requirement to display tooltips on calendars, is there any alternative way to show tooltip for calendars.